# Untarring a file with limited directory hierarchy

Tags: linux, tar

I have created a tar file in terminal. Let's say I am currently in a directory test7. I am creating a tar in my current directory of a file which is inside another directory (test8).

```
tar -czvf example.tgz ../test8/a/b
```

output:

```
example.tgz
```

Now, I untar this file using the following command :

```
tar -xzvf example.tgz
```

I get the result and a directory named as **test8** is produced.

```
$) cd test8
$) ls
-> a 
$) cd a
$) ls
-> b
```

Now I can go inside the directory **b** and see my files.

I want the output to be only the directory **a** and inside of which **b** will be present i.e.

Output after untarring that I want should be of this hierarchy : `a/b`

But not: `test8/a/b`

Can anyone please help me out with this ?

I have been through the man page of tar but couldn't get much help from it.

Comment: there is some option for `tar` that excludes the path information, but I think it eliminates **all** path. But I'm pretty sure that `cd test8 ; tar .... (as you have already done)` will store only relative paths below `test8`, making it easy to move that sub-tree to `test9` or what ever. While I didn't down vote, this is just barely a programming, and is probably more appropriate to https://unix.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -C flag while tarring. It is mentioned in the man page of tar.

```
-C, --directory=DIR
change to directory DIR
```

So, you can use this as follows :

```
tar -czvf example.tgz -C  ../test8  a/b
```

Now, if you untar example.tgz. It will have hierarchy as **a/b**  .

Hope that helps.